# Disk full error while installing linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic

Tags: package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I'm a new in the  ubuntu community. I am having trouble with 17.04: even after running most of the recommended scripts, I still cannot solve the below error. What can I do?

```
linux-signed-image-4.10.0-33-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic (= 4.10.0-33.37) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
dingi3@dingi3-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
    linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic
Suggested packages:
    fdutils linux-doc-4.10.0 | linux-source-4.10.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 57 not to upgrade.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 70.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 472330 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic_4.10.0-33.37_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.10.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic (4.10.0-33.37) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic_4.10.0-33.37_amd64.deb (--unpack):
cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.10.0-33-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic_4.10.0-33.37_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check `/boot` partition size as well as **inode usage** because here clearly mention that `failed to write (No space left on device)`, first check this.

After trying

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
```

and

```
sudo dpkg –configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

```
$ sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status    (you can use vim or gedit instead of nano)
```

Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

You can list broken packages :

```
dpkg -l | grep ^..r
```

**r** state (on the third field) means: reinst-required (package broken, re-installation required)

Comment: `--fix-missing` is the long version of `-f` so there is no need to run both, and mentioning them separately is confusing

Comment: @Zanna No, `--fix-broken` is the long version of  `-f`.